# How to include Jquery/Bootstrap files into the stack Webpack/angular2/typescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, angular, webpack

Into my project I use the stack Webpack/angular2 (with typescript).

I try to include the .js files of boostrap & jquery but I can't find a simple and well explain way...

I tried succesively to use:

- imports-loader into webpack.config
- import "jquery" into vendor-browser.ts
- require("jquery") into my ts files

I probably miss something...

I'm looking for a generic solution to include a .js file into the "window" object. Files are located into the node_modules folder.

Can someone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried my answer?

Comment: No, no time right now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understood you then ypu want to add **jquery** and **bootstrap.js** in your **angular2** project

Here is example how i did.

add a plugin so **jquery** can be loaded before bootstrap

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery"
})
```

and if you have installed bootstrap and jquery with npm then just import them in your main file

```
import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js";
import "jquery";
```

now you can test in ***browser's*** console by typing $ 
and it should show you that there is **jquery** loaded.

Answer (score 1):

[MrJSingh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5409081/mrjsingh) answer is almost correct. Except that when using `ProvidePlugin` $ will not be available in browser console. What this plugin doing is replacing every $ occurence with `require(jquery)`.

So, it **will not work** if you are using **external jquery plugins**!

Also, when using this solution, I recommend include also `window.jQuery` as some plugins only work with such notation.

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery",
            'window.jQuery': "jquery"
})
```

If you need more universal solution, consider using `expose-loader`:

```
npm install expose-loader --save-dev
```

And then this :

```
require("expose?$!jquery");
```

or this right in webpack config:

```
loaders: [
    { test: require.resolve('jquery'), loader: 'expose?jQuery!expose?$' }
]
```

Comment: How to include bootstrap css and js ?

Comment: 'window.Jquery' in the code block should be 'window.jQuery'

Answer (score 0):

One solution is this lib (for webpack)

https://github.com/shakacode/bootstrap-loader

```
Successor to bootstrap-sass-loader. 
Load Bootstrap styles and scripts in your Webpack bundle. 
This loader uses SASS to process CSS styles. 
Bootstrap 3 & 4 are supported.
```

basic example: https://github.com/shakacode/bootstrap-loader/blob/master/examples/basic

css module example: https://github.com/shakacode/bootstrap-loader/blob/master/examples/css-modules